# Выводить данные, если одно из значений равно другому

Tags: php, if

Простой вопрос, но не могу понять как правильно сформулировать.
Есть Логическая конструкция

```
if ($command == 'a') { echo 'Тут значение или выражение'; }
```

Как сделать так, что бы эта конструкция выполнялась, когда любое из значений равно значению в $command. Например если там будет `'a', 'b', 'c'` и так далее не ограниченное число значений. `if ($command == 'a', 'b', 'c') { echo 'Тут значение или выражение'; }`Как правильно сформировать эту логическую операцию.

Содержимое переменной $command это строка, те значения с которыми нужно сравнивать тоже строки.

Для чего это нужно, я бота пишу для Телеграм. И у меня при заполнении например анкеты, нужно данные записывать в базу. Но для того что бы не формировать кучу таких конструкций, хотел записать их все в 1 if.

Comment: Пример содержимого `$command` добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: сформировать из значений массив и использовать in_array подходит?

Comment: @Visman добавил

Comment: SkyFox вам уже предложил вариант http://php.net/manual/ru/function.in-array.php

Comment: @SkyFox спасибо по пробую